# String Formatting

Tags: java, string, formatting

I am currently trying to construct a program that prints Pascal's Triangles at different heights through calling a method to construct the triangle with an int parameter for height of the triangle. When trying to run my program, the first Pascal's triangle prints bu then I get an Exception error, reading this:

```
java.util.FormatFlagsConversionMismatchException: Conversion = s, Flags = 0
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failMismatch(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.checkBadFlags(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.checkGeneral(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
at java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)
at PascalsTriangle.drawTriangle(PascalsTriangle.java:19)
at PascalsTriangle.main(PascalsTriangle.java:39)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

> 

Through debugging, I noticed that there is an issue with how I formatted the String output in line 19. I am fairly new to Java programming and I have tried to work through different formatting issues in my code, but I have been stumped on how to make this work. Any suggestions on how I can prevent this exception error from happening?

Here is the code to my program:

```
public class PascalsTriangle {

  private int height;

  public void drawTriangle(int height) {
    System.out.println("A Pascal Triangle with height " + height);
    for(int i = 0; i <= height; i++) {
      int number = 1;
      System.out.format("%" + ((height-i) * 2) + "s", " ");

      for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.format("%5d", number);
        number = number * (i - j) / (j + 1);

      }
    System.out.println();   
    }
  }



  public static void main(String[] args) {

    PascalsTriangle pascal = new PascalsTriangle();

    pascal.drawTriangle(4);
    pascal.drawTriangle(10);
    pascal.drawTriangle(7);
    pascal.drawTriangle(2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since in your `for` loop you are iterating while `i <= height` then it will be possible that `i` will be equal `height` creating `"%0s"` which is incorrect (number after `%` must be positive or negative). Try adding `+ 1` in your code

```
System.out.format("%" + ((height - i + 1) * 2) + "s", " ");
//                                   ^here
```

or if `i` should be number of rows change `i <= height` into `i < height`

### update

I am not sure if that is what you meant in your comment but maybe try this way:

```
public void drawTriangle(int height) {
    System.out.println("A Pascal Triangle with height " + height);
    for (int i = 0; i <= height; i++) {
        int number = 1;
        if (i != height)
            System.out.format("%" + ((height - i) * 2) + "s", " ");

        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            if (j == 0)
                System.out.print(number);
            else
                System.out.format("%4d", number);
            number = number * (i - j) / (j + 1);

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

I added few conditions that will prevent inserting spaces at last row and when printing first `1` in a row. Also changed `%5d` to `%4d` to create more "balanced triangle". In case you would like to make it more "width" change `%4d` to `%6d` and use `"%" + ((height - i) * 3) + "s"` (3 is half of `%6d`, so for `%8d` use `((height - i) * 4))`

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. :)

Comment: The way my triangle prints in the interactions tab of my IDE prints the last lines' worth of numbers five spaces away from the left-hand side of the tab (since I format the numbers printed with %5d in line 22. Is there any way to make each row of my triangle lose five spaces so it aligns?

Comment: @user2305834 Check my updated answer. I added few conditions that will prevent inserting empty spaces at last row and will also prevent adding additional spaces when printing first `1` in a row. Also changed `%5d` to `%4d` to create more balanced triangle. In case you would like to make it more "width" change it to `%6d` and use `"%" + ((height - i) * 3) + "s", " "` (3 is half of `%6d`, for `%8d` use `((height - i) * 4)`).

Comment: This worked when I added 

    number = number * (i - j) / (j + 1);

to the loop when j == 0.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You could define a minimum padding width for the format specifier to prevent invalid `0` sized widths from occurring:

```
int padWidth = Math.max(1, ((height - i) * 2));
System.out.format("%" + padWidth + "s", " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if it isn't the answer to your question a tip: Use %% in String.format, my mistake was using just one % for just the symbol.